How many removable discontinuities can a real function have?
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. We say that $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ is a point of removable discontinuity for the function $f$ if $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0$, but $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ exists and is finite. How many points of removable discontinuties can a function have? Notice that we can find functions that have countably many removable discontinuities, for example the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = 0$ if $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$ and $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ is one of them, so the answer to the question is at least countably many. Are there any $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that have an uncountable amount of removable discontinuities?

For any $f:\mathbb R \to f:\mathbb R$, ${x: f(x+) ,, \text {exists but} f , , \text {not continuous at}, ,  x$ is at most countable. Ref: Hewitt and Stromberg's book

At most countably many, this being a consequence of a much more general result published by William Henry Young in 1908 (paper dated June 1907). See this mathoverflow answer.
